# Android in-app purchase, getting orderid as decimal value?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In the below json data from in-app purchase api, the order id is coming as decimal value, previously it used to come as integer value only.. (please assume 'X' as some number)

```
{
    "notificationId":"87356XXXXXX684814",
    "orderId":"12999763169XXXX758.13774087XXXX934",
    "packageName":"tst.package.name",
    "productId":"p8787p_31908503",
    "purchaseTime":1352692129000,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "purchaseToken":"pswjwhvxxxxxxxsyhlfbxuxpt"
},
```

So can anybody confirm that `orderId` should always be an integer and not a decimal, and if it is decimal then is it something wrong?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the API specification?

Comment: it used to come as Integer only, but recently we are seeing these Decimal values also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html for more details.

*For transactions dated 5 December 2012 or later, Google Checkout assigns a Merchant Order Number (rather than a Google Order Number) and reports the Merchant Order Number as the value of orderID.*

Comment: yes, already found that time, they actually started it earlier even before notifying us :)...